# How to find Inverse-squared of a matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, matrix-analysis

Given the matrix 
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1  &  2 &  0 \\
2  & -1 &  0 \\
0  &  0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Find $A^{-2}$

I have solved it using Cayley Hamilton theorem, but it is a long procedure. Please tell me is there another approach to solve it in a shorter way.

Comment: Have you tried to use $A^{-2} = (A^2)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: No, but its a 1 mark question, so there must be some short trick to solve it (BHU 2017 geophysics)

Comment: You should try it, $A^2$ has a very simply structure ...

Comment: Okk I am trying it, thanks!

Comment: I got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After manually calculating the square:
$$
A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Which is a diagonal matrix. Diagonal matrices have the very nice property that the inverse of $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n)$ is just $D^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}\left(\lambda_1^{-1}, \dots, \lambda_n^{-1}\right)$ (provided $\lambda_i\ne 0$ for $1\le i\le n$), and hence $(A^2)^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(1/5, 1/5, 1)$.

Comment: But in the answer the element $A_33$ is equal to 1

Comment: Correct, there's indeed a mistake in my calculation, you're right. I'll edit my solution.

Comment: Yes you got it now 

Answer (score 1):

First do $A^2$ . You will get

Given the matrix [
$A^2$ = \begin{bmatrix}5&
0&0\\0&5&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} ]
Now this is a simple matrix, so calculating its inverse is easy

You will get  [
$A^{-2}$ = \begin{bmatrix}1/5&
0&0\\0&1/5&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix} ]